# Does Tutte's theorem apply for simple graphs only

Tags: graph-theory

Tutte's theorem as stated on wikipedia says:

> A graph, $G = (V, E)$, has a perfect matching if and only if for every subset $U$ of $V$, the subgraph induced by $V − U$ has at most $|U|$ connected components with an odd number of vertices.

Is the graph $G$ assumed to be simple? If not, why does Andersen's proof of Tutte's theorem [here](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0095895671900414/1-s2.0-0095895671900414-main.pdf?_tid=c29fdd44-d4c9-11e5-b370-00000aacb361&acdnat=1455640052_cc860f78b2729bbc3ec35ee85ecef8d0) begin by considering only simple graphs?

Comment: A graph with multiple edges has a perfect matching if and only if the underlying simple graph has a perefect matching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement of Tutte's theorem does not really mention edges. So suppose there are possibly loops and multiple edges between vertices. Then $V-U$ has exactly the same number of connected components as the graph you'd get by removing the extra edges and loops because deleting a vertex from a graph  removes all the edges and loops do not do anything for connectivity.

This of course, is assuming that whatever notion of matching we are using for a multigraph does not allow loops as part of the matching, for otherwise we could take the standard example of a 3-regular graph without a perfect matching and add one loop to every vertex to obtain a perfect "matching" consisting of just the loops.

[image]

Comment: What about we change the statement (which I feel is really about certificates) to a component is odd if it is odd and has no loop

Comment: You will have to make a new question defining the terms certificate, component and what it means for a component to be odd.

Comment: @RDK https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3450838/tuttes-theorem-with-loops-and-on-matching-a-subset     Also I stated a component is odd if it is odd and has no loop. So one can ask if the maximum number of vertices in a matching of a graph with loops (where a loop means a vertex can be matched with itself ) is k less than the number of vertices then does there necessarily exist  a set of vertices A such that G \ A has k + |A| odd components?